# Numpy multi-dimensional slicing with multiple boolean arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I'm trying to use individual 1-dimensional boolean arrays to slice a multi-dimension array. For some reason, this code doesn't work:

```
>>> a = np.ones((100, 200, 300, 2))
>>> a.shape
(100, 200, 300, 2)
>>> m1 = np.asarray([True]*200)
>>> m2 = np.asarray([True]*300)
>>> m2[-1] = False
>>> a[:,m1,m2,:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (200,) (299,) 
>>> m2 = np.asarray([True]*300) # try again with all 300 dimensions True
>>> a[:,m1,m2,:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (200,) (300,)
```

But this works just fine:

```
>>> a = np.asarray([[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16]]])
>>> a.shape
(2, 3, 2)
>>> m1 = np.asarray([True, False, True])
>>> m2 = np.asarray([True, False])
>>> a[:,m1,m2]
array([[ 1,  5],
       [11, 15]])
```

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong in the first example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: The number of True elements in `m1` and `m2` must match, unless one of them has only one True term.

Also distinguish between 'diagonal' indexing and 'rectangular' indexing.  This is about indexing, not slicing.  The dimensions with `:` are just along for the ride.

### Initial ideas

I can get your first case working with:

```
In [137]: a=np.ones((100,200,300,2))

In [138]: m1=np.ones((200,),bool)    
In [139]: m2=np.ones((300,),bool)
In [140]: m2[-1]=False

In [141]: I,J=np.ix_(m1,m2)

In [142]: a[:,I,J,:].shape
Out[142]: (100, 200, 299, 2)
```

`np.ix_` turns the 2 boolean arrays into broadcastable index arrays

```
In [143]: I.shape
Out[143]: (200, 1)
In [144]: J.shape
Out[144]: (1, 299)
```

Note that this picks 200 'rows' in one dimension, and 299 in the other.

<strike>I'm not sure why this kind of reworking of the arrays is needed in this case, but not in the 2nd</strike>

```
In [154]: b=np.arange(2*3*2).reshape((2,3,2))

In [155]: n1=np.array([True,False,True])
In [156]: n2=np.array([True,False])

In [157]: b[:,n1,n2]
Out[157]: 
array([[ 0,  4],      # shape (2,2)
       [ 6, 10]])
```

Taking the same `ix_` strategy produces the same values but a different shape:

```
In [164]: b[np.ix_(np.arange(b.shape[0]),n1,n2)]
# or I,J=np.ix_(n1,n2);b[:,I,J]
Out[164]: 
array([[[ 0],
        [ 4]],

       [[ 6],
        [10]]])

In [165]: _.shape
Out[165]: (2, 2, 1)
```

Both cases use all rows of the 1st dimension. The `ix` one picks 2 'rows' of the 2nd dim, and 1 column of the last, resulting the (2,2,1) shape.  The other picks `b[:,0,0]` and `b[0,2,0]` terms, resulting (2,2) shape.
(see my addenda as to why both are simply broadcasting).
<strike>These are all cases of advanced indexing, with boolean and numeric indexes.  One can study the docs, or one can play around.  Sometimes it's more fun to do the later.  :)</strike>

(I knew that `ix_` was good for adding the necessary `np.newaxis` to arrays so can be broadcast together, but didn't realize that worked with boolean arrays as well - it uses `np.nonzero()` to convert boolean to indices.)

### Resolution

Underlying this is, I think, a confusion over 2 modes of indexing. which might called 'diagonal' and 'rectangular' (or element-by-element selection versus block selection).  To illustrate look at a small 2d array

```
In [73]: M=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [74]: M
Out[74]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

and 2 simple numeric indexes

```
In [75]: m1=np.arange(2); m2=np.arange(2)
```

They can be used 2 ways:

```
In [76]: M[m1,m2]
Out[76]: array([0, 4])
```

and

```
In [77]: M[m1[:,None],m2]
Out[77]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
```

The 1st picks 2 points, the `M[0,0]` and `M[1,1]`.  This kind of indexing lets us pick out the diagonals of an array.

The 2nd picks 2 rows and from that 2 columns. This is the kind of indexing the `np.ix_` produces.  The 1st picks 2 points, the `M[0,0]` and `M[1,1]`.  This a 'rectangular' form of indexing.

Change `m2` to 3 values:

```
In [78]: m2=np.arange(3)
In [79]: M[m1[:,None],m2]   # returns a 2x3
Out[79]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
In [80]: M[m1,m2]   # produces an error
...
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

But if `m2` has just one element, we don't get the broadcast error - because the size 1 dimension can be expanded during broadcasting:

```
In [81]: m2=np.arange(1)
In [82]: M[m1,m2]
Out[82]: array([0, 3])
```

Now change the index arrays to boolean, each matching the length of the respective dimensions, 2 and 3.

```
In [91]: m1=np.ones(2,bool); m2=np.ones(3,bool)
In [92]: M[m1,m2]
...
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
In [93]: m2[2]=False  # m1 and m2 each have 2 True elements
In [94]: M[m1,m2]
Out[94]: array([0, 4])
In [95]: m2[0]=False   # m2 has 1 True element
In [96]: M[m1,m2]
Out[96]: array([1, 4])
```

With 2 and 3 True terms we get an error, but with 2 and 2 or 2 and 1 it runs - just as though we'd used the indices of the True elements: `np.nonzero(m2)`.

To apply this to your examples.  In the first, `m1` and `m2` have 200 and 299 True elements.  `a[:,m1,m2,:]` fails because of a mismatch in the number of True terms.

In the 2nd, they have 2 and 1 True terms, with nonzero indices of `[0,2]` and `[0]`, which can be broadcast to `[0,0]`.  So it runs.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html
explains boolean array indexing in terms of `nonzero` and `ix_`.

> Combining multiple Boolean indexing arrays or a Boolean with an integer indexing array can best be understood with the obj.nonzero() analogy. The function ix_ also supports boolean arrays and will work without any surprises.

### Addenda

On further thought the distinction between 'diagonal' and 'block/rectangular' indexing might be more my mental construct that `numpys`.  Underlying both is the concept of broadcasting.

Take the `n1` and `n2` booleans, and get their `nonzero` equivalents:

```
In [107]: n1
Out[107]: array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
In [108]: np.nonzero(n1)
Out[108]: (array([0, 2], dtype=int32),)
In [109]: n2
Out[109]: array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
In [110]: np.nonzero(n2)
Out[110]: (array([0], dtype=int32),)
```

Now try broadcasting in the 'diagonal' and 'rectangular' modes:

```
In [105]: np.broadcast_arrays(np.array([0,2]),np.array([0]))
Out[105]: [array([0, 2]), 
           array([0, 0])]

In [106]: np.broadcast_arrays(np.array([0,2])[:,None],np.array([0]))
Out[106]: 
[array([[0],
        [2]]), 
 array([[0],
        [0]])]
```

One produces `(2,)` arrays, the other `(2,1)`.

Comment: Interesting analysis and thanks for the workaround. Still curious why this is required in the one case.

Comment: I figured out that when using the 'diagonal' style of indexing, the number of True elements in the 2 boolean arrays much match (or be 1).  See my edits.

Comment: I'm still trying to grasp this logic. Will take me a while to digest it properly, but thanks for figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simple workaround:

```
a[:,m1,:,:][:,:,m2,:]
```